# Добавить к каждому элементу в строке, кроме последнего

Tags: python

Есть функция, которая разбивает строку на буквы и каждой букве добавляет ***.

```
def two_sort(array):
    new_str = ''.join(word + "***" for word in array)
    return new_str
```

Как сделать, чтобы к последней букве она ничего не добавляла?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так:

```
def two_sort(array):
    new_str = '***'.join(array)
    return new_str
```